# With seaborn.facetgrid, how do I specify the color of a mapped scatter plot to reflect the values of a column in the data frame?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to create a FacetGrid of scatterplots where the color of the points is defined by a column in the plotted data frame. However, it seems like I cannot pass a column name to the `c=` parameter of `plt.scatter` when I map it, since it is interpreted as a string of colors rathen than a column name:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style='white')

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
g = sns.FacetGrid(iris, row='species', size=4)
g.map(plt.scatter, 'sepal_width', 'sepal_length', c='petal_length')
```

Out:

```
/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.pyc in to_rgba_array(self, c, alpha)
    420             result = np.zeros((nc, 4), dtype=np.float)
    421             for i, cc in enumerate(c):
--> 422                 result[i] = self.to_rgba(cc, alpha)
    423             return result
    424 

/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.pyc in to_rgba(self, arg, alpha)
    374         except (TypeError, ValueError) as exc:
    375             raise ValueError(
--> 376                 'to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "%s"\n%s' % (str(arg), exc))
    377 
    378     def to_rgba_array(self, c, alpha=None):

ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "p"
to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "p"
could not convert string to float: p
```

The result I expected was the same as from `plt.scatter(iris.sepal_width, iris.sepal_length, c=iris.petal_length)`

[image]

I tried briefly with `sns.regplot`, but it seemed to encounter the same problems. If I do not specify the `row=` or `col=` parameters of FacetGrid, I can input `c=iris.petal_length` for the expected results.

Is there a way to get create a FacetGrid where the data is grouped by row or column and the data points are colored according to a column in the data frame?

Comment: Your code is missing where you define `g`.

Comment: Sorry, added `g = sns.FacetGrid(iris, row='species', size=4)` above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables identified as columns in the DataFrame need to correspond with positional arguments in the plotting function. The easiest thing to do is write a little wrapper function around `plt.scatter` that makes its signature `scatter(x, y, c)` instead of `scatter(x, y, s, c)`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style='white')

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
g = sns.FacetGrid(iris, row='species', size=4)

def scatter(x, y, c, **kwargs):
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, **kwargs)

g.map(scatter, 'sepal_width', 'sepal_length', 'petal_length')
```

Comment: This seems to only work if I remove the kwargs from the scatter function (i.e. return `plt.scatter(x, y, c=c)`)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by specifying the `hue` parameter.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(iris, col='species', hue='petal_length', size=4)
g.map(plt.scatter, 'sepal_width', 'sepal_length')
```

That generates this plot: [image: this plot].

Comment: Since seaborn 0.9 it is also possible to use `sns.scatterplot` with a `hue`.

Comment: `hue` will set the `color` argument of scatter, not the `c` argument

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying do to?

```
g.map(plt.scatter, 'sepal_width', 'sepal_length', c=iris.petal_length)
```

Comment: I tried that previously, but it only works when `row=` or `col=` are not used when calling `sns.FacetGrid`.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is that the FacetGrid's `map` function inadvertently manages the values for `color` by adding them to your plotting function's `**kwargs`.
If you want to specify your own `c` or `color` for the scatter plot, you can delete the color argument from kwargs in a small wrapper, and then specify your own without any error:

```
def custom_scatter(x, y, c, **kwargs):
  del kwargs["color"]
  plt.scatter(x, y, c = c, **kwargs)
```

Now you can use `custom_scatter` for the mapping:

```
g.map(custom_scatter, 'sepal_width', 'sepal_length', 'petal_length')
```